# IE does not recognize my script

Tags: jquery-selectors

hello friends I have a big problem with internet explorer, I made a date validation using "select" with jquery, in Mozilla and crome works, but **IE** does nothing. Please I need help!

Comment: We need examples of what you have tried already to have any chance of helping you. Please show us your jquery code and html markup

Comment: the problem is only in IE in the other works!!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZnH0TZa1 here is the entire code!

Answer (score 1):

Your JS code calls for elements that aren't created in IE version less than 7 - thus it does nothing. See below:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.createElement("#date-star-month");
   document.createElement("#date-star-year");
   document.createElement("#date-finish-month");
   document.createElement("#date-finish-year");
   document.createElement("#date-star-month option");
   document.createElement("#date-star-year option");
   document.createElement("#date-finish-month option");
   document.createElement("#date-finish-year option");
   document.createElement("year_star");
   document.createElement("year_finish");
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

This will not work in IE older than 7 - tested on 9, didn't work, until I ran IE9 in quasi-IE7 mode.

### Additional pointers

1. Would be much easier to answer your question if you would be more specific.
2. Adding your code was a good move, do that from the start.
3. Too bad you didn't:

   - let us know what the validation function is supposed to do
   - on what browsers (with their versions) have you tested this
4. Also, if you state your intentions (why do you need that data validation, what it must do, etc.) you can get extra tips to achieve this in other (maybe better or easier) way.